# pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError:

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

when I try to change datatype to datetime format I faced above key error
This is the code that I have been using for this project. I used a shop data to make sales forecasting system but I tried so many levels I couldn't understand what it means by keyError.

```
import warnings
import pandas as pd  

pizzahome=pd.read_excel('E:\machine learninig projects\pizzahome\sales.xlsx')

pizzahome['da'] = pd.to_datetime(pizzahome["da"])
```

This is the error I'm facing

```
E:\python\venv\Scripts\python.exe "E:/machine learninig projects/machinelearningpractice.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2889, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 97, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'da'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/machine learninig projects/machinelearningpractice.py", line 18, in <module>
    pizzahome['da'] = pd.to_datetime(pizzahome['da'])
  File "E:\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2902, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "E:\python\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2891, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'da'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

plese anybody help me to find out solution for it

Comment: I've answered your question, but you really didn't ask a question. Please review all of the guides on this forum. You also posted a bunch of irrelevant code. The only part that's failing is the line in the stack trace ```pizzahome['da'] = pd.to_datetime(pizzahome['da'])```, which is just a simple pandas error

Comment: As said by @Brennan; any code that comes *after* the error is irrlevant to the issue (never executed) and should not be posted here. The same holds true for irrelevant imports (edited out).

Answer (score 2):

A KeyError means the key you gave pandas isn’t valid. In your case, there is no column named “da” in the Excel file you are reading.

Before doing anything with the data frame, use
`print(df.columns)` to see what keys are available.

In your case

```py
print(pizzahome.columns)
```

That output will not include "da"

#### Example:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> data = {'A':["10/1/20","11/1/20"], 'B':[3,4]}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> df.columns
Index(['A', 'B'], dtype='object')
>>> df['C'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])
>>> df.columns
Index(['A', 'B', 'C'], dtype='object')
>>> df                                                                                                                                                     
   A        B C
0  10/1/20  3 2020-10-01
1  11/1/20  4 2020-11-01
```

Comment: No, In my Excel file a column with 'Date' name, I used that name too but it shows the same error

Comment: Can you provide the excel file? Either the column name is different from what you are entering as the key, or your df does not have any headers

Comment: what do you mean as df?

Comment: df = “DataFrame”. Did you see what I posted on my answer? I gave you a full example of how it works

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed my error that was a problem in my excel sheet's column